# Communicating to virtual comport converter via TCP/IP

Tags: tcp-ip

Our test program communicate with test device true virtual com port converter. The problem is that we are moving project to several different PC and every PC assign different COM port number to converter.

I am looking for a solution, how to communicate with device that PC recognizes it as a virtual port via TCP/IP communication.

Is there any converter TCP/IP to virtual COM port? I found TCP/IP converter to for example RS232, but I don't know how to communicate to virtual COM port device.

[image]

Comment: This isn't an electronics problem. You are asking for a device which can convert a TCP/IP to USB for the device? Any PC can do that. Also, the problem is solved by remembering to open a different COM port on each different PC, so you need to modify your test program to remember which port to open.

Comment: most languages have a way to recover from error. Surely try comport number, on error try next one, would allow your program to find the appropriate number?